# Как создать таблицу без колонки id?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Я создаю таблицу SQLite с тремя столбцами и колонкой id. Можно как-то ее не создавать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без колонки `_id` не будут работать все классы фреймворка Android, которые взаимодействуют с БД SQLite, в частности `Cursor`. Вам придется писать свои, не думаю, что вы этого хотите.
Кроме того, вся работа с БД построена на связях таблиц (один к одному, один ко многим, многие ко многим), которые реализуются через `ID`.

Но вы конечно можете не создавать этой колонки, если считаете, что она вам в самом деле не нужна.
Просто удалите строку из скрипта создания таблицы `CREATE_TABLE` с записью:

```
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Comment: Пожалуй мне эта колонка нужна... :)